# Как полностью удалить MySQL с Debian?

Tags: debian, mysql

Мне нужно полностью удалить  MySQL на oC Debian.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 6):

apt-get принимает маски в инпуте, поэтому полное удаление делается просто:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libmysqlclient-dev* libmysqlclient20* libmysqlcppconn-dev* libmysqlcppconn7v5* mysql-client* mysql-client-5.7* mysql-client-core-5.7*
  mysql-common* mysql-server* mysql-server-5.6* mysql-server-5.7* mysql-server-core-5.7*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
After this operation, 176 MB disk space will be freed.
```

удаляет все, относящееся к mysql без всяких гаданий с указанием версий и т.д.

собственно говоря, вы так можете многие другие пакеты удалять :-)

P.S. так вы можете удалить ***слишком много пакетов***, если например сделаете

`sudo apt-get remove my*`, частью вывода может быть, например:

```
Package 'mythnetvision' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mythnews' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mythplugins' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mythtv' is not installed, so not removed
```

поэтому пользуйтесь осторожно мощью apt.

Answer (score 5):

Вначале пишем

```
 dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
```

и выписываем все ненужные пакеты. Потом с помощью `apt-get remove имяпакета` удаляем по одному или пачкой.

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get remove mysql-server-5.0
```

Вместо 5.0 ваша версия (`apt-cache search mysql`).

Comment: ```apt-cache search``` не покажет установленную

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get remove --purge %metapacketName%
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - использовать aptitude или synaptic. Так проще будет удалять пакеты

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo aptitude purge mysql-common mysql-server mysql-common  
sudo aptitude install mysql-common mysql-server mysql-common
```

Решает проблемы с запуском MySQL. Проверено

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score -1):

Узнаем версии:

`apt-cache search mysql`

Удаляем сервер:

`apt-get remove mysql-server-5.5`

Удаляем клиент:

`apt-get remove mysql-client-5.5`

Comment: ```apt-cache search``` не покажет установленные версии, он покажет только доступные для установки. Соответственно не узнать какая версия установлена